# Como implementar método para validar Token en Node Js

Tags: javascript, nodejs

[image: Si tengo servicio para Registrar un Token]

Si tengo este servicio para registrar un Token

[image: Y tengo este controlador para registrar un Token]

Y tengo esté método para registrar un Token.

Como se crearía uno que permita Validar un Token: Que al pasar el Token por un parametro, arroje si es valido, si existe si no existe  y  cuando se  vence dicho token.

Agradezco sus respuestas, estoy aprendiendo Node JS y me gustaría poder aprender a hacer esto.

Muchas Gracias

Desde Acá lo nuevo que he hecho:
Esto es lo que llevo hasta el momento pero me saca error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
(Como se pasa si esta en el mismo usuarioController?)

Me Saca el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, te sugiero que uses código en vez de imágenes. Las imágenes pueden ayudar en cierta forma, pero en este caso siempre será mejor que pegues el código. Para eso dispones de las herramientas adecuadas. Te invito a hacer clic en [edit] para que realices los cambios necesarios. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Hola Juan Martín Taborda García.
Lo que podrías hacer sería crear un middleware de esta forma:

isAuth.js --->

```
//invocamos las dependencias necesarias
    const jwtSimple = require('jwt-simple');
    const secret = "s_e-C_r-E-t_A";
    const moment = require('moment');


    exports.ensureAuth = async (req, res, next) => {
   //Comprobamos si existe la cabecera de autenticación
        if(!req.headers.authorization){
            return res.status(403).send({message: "No existe una cabecera de autenticación"});
        }
    //recogemos el token de la cabecera. Partimos el string porque viene con la palabra Bearer antes del chorro de caracteres del token
        let token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
        let payload;
        try{
         //Comprobamos que el token coincide
            payload = await jwtSimple.decode(token, secret);
         //Comprobamos que el token no ha expirado 
            if (payload.exp <= moment.unix()) {
                return res.status(401).send({message: 'Tu conexión ha expirado. Vuelve a hacer login.'});
            }
        }catch(e){
            return res.status(500).send({message: "Ha ocurrido un error: (ensureAuth) - " + e.message});
        }
    //asignamos el payload el usuario de la peticion
        req.user = payload;
    //Usamos next() para seguir el curso de la aplicación
        next();
    }
```

Este Middleware que hemos creado lo usaremos en las rutas. Ejemplo:

```
const auth = require('./middlewares/isAuth');
const userController = require('../controllers/user-controller.js');
                        //Aquí se realizará la comprobación. Interrogación porque el parámetro es opcional.
router.get('/listUsers/:id?', auth.ensureAuth, userController.getUsers);

module.exports = router;
```

**EDITADO:**

Perdona por lo de la función getUsers(). En este caso se encontraría como puedes ver en el controlador de usuarios, y con ella recogemos los usuarios que hay en la base de datos.

```
async function getUsers(req, res){
    if(req.params.id){
        try{
            let id = req.params.id;
            let user = await userModel.findOne({_id:id});
            return res.status(200).send({message: "Ususario encontrado.", user: user});
        }catch(e){
            return res.status(500).send({message: "Ha ocurrido un error: (getUsers) userController -  " + e.message});
        }
    }else{
        try{
            let users = await userModel.find({});
            return res.status(200).send({message: "Usuarios encontrados.", users: users});
        }catch(e){
            return res.status(500).send({message: "Ha ocurrido un error: (getUsers) userController - " + e.message});
        }
    }
}
```

Está hecho un poco rápido pero supongo que puedas entender por donde va la cosa más o menos.

Espero que te ayude, cualquier duda, me comentas. 
Un saludo.

**SEGUNDA EDICION**

"getUsers" se encuentra en este caso en "userController" el cual contiene varias funciones relacionadas con el modelo de usuario. En este controlador lo exportamos al final del fichero con:

```
async function getUsers(req, res){
   /****** Código ******/
}

module.exports = getUsers
```

o si tienes varias funciones que exportar lo puedes hacer de esta forma:

```
module.exports = {
   getUsers,
   saveUser,
   deleteUser
}
```

Después en las rutas de usuario (fichero) lo importamos:

```
const userController = require('donde/esté/el/fichero');
```

y para usarlo en la ruta hariamos lo siguiente:

```
router.get('/listUsers/:id?', auth.ensureAuth, userController.getUsers);
```

Por otra parte lo que puedes hacer es escribir la función como callback en la ruta:

```
router.get('/listUsers/:id?', auth.ensureAuth, function(req, res){
   /***** Código de la función no tenemos porque asignarle un nombre *****/
});
```

Comment: Hola H.Dias, te agradezco por tu ayuda. Tengo una inquietud, este userController.getUsers de donde lo trae

Comment: Ya logre implementar todo lo que dices, pero solo me falta agarrar ese userController.getUsers, en mi caso el controlador es UsuarioController, pero no entiendo ese .getUsers que es

Comment: He editado la respuesta.

Comment: Hola H.Diaz, resulta que estoy haciendo lo del router.get en el mismo usuarioController, como le paso userController.getUsers como parametro a ese metodo si estoy en la misma clase, me saca un error y me dice que no esta definido.

Comment: Por favor mira las ultimas ediciones que he hecho por aca, allí muestro los pantallazos de lo que he hecho, pero aún no consigo dar con la solución, yo creo que estoy a un paso de lograrlo, solo es saber llamar ese router.get en mi caso.

Comment: He realizado una segunda edición explicando un poco más como podrías hacer lo que buscas. Lo que si que es necesario aclarar es que en tu caso usar "this" y no es necesario, si tienes la función declarada en el mismo fichero puedes llamarla simplemente con su nombre, pero no te recomiendo que tengas todo en un mismo fichero. Intenta "modularizar" distribuyendo rutas, controladores, modelos, etc. para que de esta forma puedas mantener el código en un futuro de una forma más sencilla.